# Visual Studio: working in sync in a team with a read-only library project added to the VS solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, tortoisesvn

I've written a DLL library in C# that consist of an API for communicating and manipulating our products. I want it to be used by QA guys in our team for building testing tools in .NET environment. As oppose to the principle of encapsulation (one might suggest...), I would like the QA guys to be able to see the actual implementations of the API methods in the DLL (for example, when they click "go to definition" in Visual Studio) instead of just seeing the declarations/annotations from the metadata.

I don't want them to be able to change the actual DLL and I don't want them to build the DLL each time they build their new project, so I can't simply add the library project to their VS solutions.

One theoretical way that crossed my mind is to maybe add the library project to each of their VS solutions as read-only (if possible?) and also instruct them never to build it (only build their own new project) or maybe even lock it from building (if possible?). The problem is that ideally, I want them to be able to update the library project inside their VS solution to the newest revision from the version control system (I'm using Tortoise SVN) in a press of one button somehow, along with the updated (built) DLL file (updating the DLL file into their solution folder is easy and can be done even in a simple batch file, but I'm not sure how to update the project files themselves...).

Of course I would like all the above in some sort of a template, so that the preparations for developing a new QA tool would be quick and easy.

I found this issue difficult to formulate (I hope I was clear enough), but I'm sure this is quite a common issue when working in a team (which I'm not used to). Can anyone help me understand the right way of handling this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for a [source server](http://brockreeve.com/post/2009/10/23/Symbol-Server-Setup.aspx). Apparently (though I have no personal experience with it myself) the tools are already there to work against subversion. This seems like a better option than having them all keep working copies (even read-only ones) of the source files.

Added note: the link above describes the author's implementation of a source server with perforce, not subversion, but you should be able to find other links (like [this one](http://sander.rijken.info/post/2962017715/sourceserver-indexing-and-subversion), and perhaps better ones) discussing subversion in particular.